# Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps, illegalargumentexception

I have an application with three tabs.

Each tab has its own layout .xml file. The main.xml has its own map fragment. It's the one that shows up when the application first launches.

Everything works fine except for when I change between tabs. If I try to switch back to the map fragment tab, I get this error. Switching to and between other tabs works just fine.

What could be wrong here?

This is my main class and my main.xml, as well as a relevant class that I use ( you will also find the error log at the bottom )

**main class**

```
package com.nfc.demo;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NFCDemoActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        bar.addTab(bar
                .newTab()
                .setText("Map")
                .setTabListener(
                        new TabListener<MapFragment>(this, "map",
                                MapFragment.class)));
        bar.addTab(bar
                .newTab()
                .setText("Settings")
                .setTabListener(
                        new TabListener<SettingsFragment>(this, "settings",
                                SettingsFragment.class)));
        bar.addTab(bar
                .newTab()
                .setText("About")
                .setTabListener(
                        new TabListener<AboutFragment>(this, "about",
                                AboutFragment.class)));

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
        }
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tab", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements
            ActionBar.TabListener {
        private final Activity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<T> mClass;
        private final Bundle mArgs;
        private Fragment mFragment;

        public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
            this(activity, tag, clz, null);
        }

        public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz,
                Bundle args) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
            mArgs = args;

            // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab,
            // probably from a previously saved state. If so, deactivate
            // it, because our initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
            mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
            if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(mFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (mFragment == null) {
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(),
                        mArgs);
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
            } else {
                ft.attach(mFragment);
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (mFragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mFragment);
            }
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                         .show();
        }
    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**relevant class ( MapFragment.java )**

```
package com.nfc.demo;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**error**

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: 
     Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
   at com.nfc.demo.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:15)
   at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1255)
   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
     Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f040005, tag null, or 
     parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for 
     com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
   at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4722)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
   ... 19 more
```

Comment: try this - return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); instead of super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

Comment: you shuold not add you fragment when savedInstanceState is not null.

Comment: Take a look to this comment. It might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562416/error-inflating-class-fragment-duplicate-id-illegalargumentexception/31723342#31723342

Comment: Please change the accepted answer! You picked a very bad answer which create memory leaks! The correct answer is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19815266/902276

Answer (score 400, accepted):

[The answer Matt suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484640) works, but it causes the map to be recreated and redrawn, which isn't always desirable.
After lots of trial and error, I found a solution that works for me:

```
private static View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
    }
    return view;
}
```

For good measure, here's "map.xml" (R.layout.map) with R.id.mapFragment (android:id="@+id/mapFragment"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this helps, but I can't guarantee that it doesn't have any adverse effects.

**Edit:** There were some adverse effects, such as when exiting the application and starting it again. Since the application isn't necessarily completely shut down (but just put to sleep in the background), the previous code i submitted would fail upon restarting the application. I've updated the code to something that works for me, both going in & out of the map and exiting and restarting the application, I'm not too happy with the try-catch bit, but it seem to work well enough. <strike>When looking at the stack trace it occurred to me that I could just check if the map fragment is in the FragmentManager, no need for the try-catch block, code updated.</strike>

**More edits:** It turns out that you need that try-catch after all. Just checking for the map fragment turned out not to work so well after all. Blergh.

Comment: This is a wrong answer -1! You are leaking an activity using static modifier for a View. The root cause of this issue is probably another leaked activity, that cannot be garbage collected because you're keeping a strong reference pointing to it. In case there is an InflateException thrown, you're using a view that has context of destroyed activity! Better find other memory leaks in your app, this will solve all the problems.

Comment: I guess we can use WeakReference to avoid memory leak?

Comment: This works for me too +1. You're not obligated to use static reference of view

Comment: Don't do this!!! It cause memory leak. The only reason this happens is because you are inflating a fragment from XML inside another fragment. You are NOT supposed to do that! You should use the ChildFragmentManager and add the fragment in onViewCreated()!

Comment: @KarolŻygłowicz is right. No need for static reference !!

Comment: "but it cause the map to be recreated and redrawn, which isn't always desirable."
This solution does same thing too, if view exists, it removes and then reinflates

Comment: Yes, this will indeed leak the activity. Found a working solution in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27592123/683763. The idea is to manually remove the `SupportMapFragment` in `onDestroyView` method.

Answer (score 286):

The problem is that what you are trying to do shouldn't be done. You shouldn't be inflating fragments inside other fragments. From Android's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments):

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout
>   includes a <fragment>. Nested fragments are only supported when added
>   to a fragment dynamically.

While you may be able to accomplish the task with the hacks presented here, I highly suggest you don't do it. Its impossible to be sure that these hacks will handle what each new Android OS does when you try to inflate a layout for a fragment containing another fragment.

The only Android-supported way to add a fragment to another fragment is via a transaction from the child fragment manager.

Simply change your XML layout into an empty container (add an ID if needed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the Fragment `onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)` method:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("mapFragment");
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.mapFragmentContainer, mapFragment, "mapFragment");
        ft.commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(callback);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733299/initialize-mapfragment-programmatically-with-maps-api-v2 for examples of creating a map fragment programmatically and initializing the map.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239175/java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed-using-fragments for workaround for apparent bug in child fragment support.

Comment: I encountered this issue on `4.3` when using a `SupportMapFragment` defined in XML.  Dynamically creating the fragment and injecting it into a container view resolved the issue. See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15813151/1747491).

Comment: Very useful answer. How can we do a callback to onCreate() main function ?

Comment: shouldn't you use `newInstance()` to create the map fragment?

Comment: How are you still referencing mapFragment in the code if you've just removed it from the layout file? Is it moved elsewhere after this?

Comment: Ah, I see, you do it by tag instead of id, which I assume must create one programatically instead of taking it from a layout file?

Comment: According to doc, use `SupportMapFragment.newInstance();` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map

Comment: I highly recommend this solution as it is not violating anything and got not leak so far. It is the way I am using when I am dealing with fragment inside other fragment. Or you can create an other module to deal with the map aside and call it whenever you want it but its a long process.

Comment: perfect answer ! you saved my night

Answer (score 186):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by manually removing the `MapFragment` in the `onDestroy()` method of the `Fragment` class.  Here is code that works and references the `MapFragment` by ID in the XML:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                         .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (f != null) 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
}
```

If you don't remove the `MapFragment` manually, it will hang around so that it doesn't cost a lot of resources to recreate/show the map view again. It seems that keeping the underlying `MapView` is great for switching back and forth between tabs, but when used in fragments this behavior causes a duplicate `MapView` to be created upon each new `MapFragment` with the same ID.  The solution is to manually remove the `MapFragment` and thus recreate the underlying map each time the fragment is inflated.

I also noted this in another answer [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14466954/61594)].

Comment: It makes the app crash when clicking on the device's home button, with the "Don't keep activities" in the developer options.

Comment: this works, but if i rotate my screen, my app crashes with this exception: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Comment: For those who may be interested, you can eliminate the exception caused by screen rotation by storing inital orientation in fragment's constructor and calling the above transaction only if orientation was NOT changed. If it was changed, there is no need to struggle with duplicate ID, because it is not there when view is created anew after rotation. I can edit the answer and provide a code snippet, if Matt does not mind.

Comment: Hmm for me the map fragment is not being removed. I must be doing something wrong but if I call getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments(), the fragment remains after the calling remove(f).commit. Does anyone have any idea why? (I replaced getFragManager with getSupportFragManager)

Comment: Need to also catch the `IllegalStateException`.  I think this won't cause other problems since it will only happen when the activity gets destroyed, and in that case the `MapFragment` gets removed correctly.  Checking if the activity is destroyed instead of try/catch works, but on one of my devices crashes using the method `activity.isDestroyed()`.

Comment: commitAllowingStateLoss will avoid the IllegalStateException exception.

Comment: This way has some problems with onDestroy of Activity and Fragment.

Comment: Hi when orientation changed, it is giving exception..java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState..tried with commitAllowingStateLoss(); but no use..need help..

Comment: For me the map fragment is removed but its not recreated again when i come back to the fragment. The onCreateView is not called if also use onDestroyView

Comment: This fixed the problem but caused my app to crash on exit while the fragment was visible.

Comment: This worked fine for me, i just used a try catch into onDestroy method.

Comment: Only this approach work perfectly!!! Need to remove inner fragments inside fragment

Answer (score 23):

This is my answer:

1, Create a layout xml like following:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

2, in the Fragment class, add a google map programmatically.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass. Activities that
 * contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MapFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface to handle
 * interaction events. Use the {@link MapFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 * 
 */
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.map_container, mMapFragment).commit();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Log.d("Attach", "on attach");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Comment: `mMapFragment.getMap();` returns `null`. Any idea why?

Comment: @AnasAzeem , creating fragment programmatically solves the problem exactly,you dont have to get mMap for the solution maybe in your case.

Comment: @AnasAzeem you should use get getMapAsync which will return a map instance correctly after initializing (in the background). This is the "correct" way of working with google maps and has nothing to do with fragments

Answer (score 10):

1. As mentioned by @Justin Breitfeller, @Vidar Wahlberg solution is a hack which might not work in future version of Android.
2. @Vidar Wahlberg perfer a hack because other solution might "cause the map to be recreated and redrawn, which isn't always desirable". Map redraw could be prevented by maintaining the old map fragment, rather than creating a new instance every time.
3. @Matt solution doesn't work for me (IllegalStateException)
4. As quoted by @Justin Breitfeller, "You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a . Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically."

My solution:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_list, container, false);

    // init
    //mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    // don't recreate fragment everytime ensure last map location/state are maintain
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // R.id.map is a layout
    transaction.replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Desmond Your solution worked flawlessly for me. The only thing you need to remember is NOT to create the map in the layout. Map creation in this solution is embedded in the code so change <fragment android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"> to e.g. <LinearLayout id="@+id/map />

Answer (score 9):

Declare SupportMapFragment object globally

```
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
```

In onCreateView() method put below code

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

In onDestroyView() put below code

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
   super.onDestroyView();

    if (mapFragment != null)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment).commit();
}
```

In your xml file put below code

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.abc.Driver.fragment.FragmentHome"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Above code solved my problem and it's working fine

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend `replace()` rather than `attach()`/`detach()` in your tab handling.

Or, switch to `ViewPager`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Pager) showing a `ViewPager`, with tabs, hosting 10 maps.

Comment: But replace give outofmemry error than what should do if we use detach window than map issue occur.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
if (view == null) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nearbyplaces, container, false);
}
```

That's it, if not null you don't need to reinitialize it removing from parent is unnecessary step.

Comment: This is the best solution for my case.I was getting that error as a result of using two fragments for my navigation graph and this fixed my issue.

Comment: This is the best solution for my case.I was getting that error as a result of using two fragments for my navigation graph and this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning or inflating layout twice, just check to see if you only inflate once.

Comment: Great Catch! I would have looked for hours but didnt noticed this. Thanks @MahdiGiveie

Answer (score 2):

I have lost hours today to find the reason, fortunately this issue is not because of MapFragment implementation, fnfortunately, this does not work because nested fragments are only supported through support library from rev 11.

My implementation has an activity with actionbar (in tabbed mode) with two tabs (no viewpager), one having the map and the other having a list of entries. Of course I've been quite naive to use MapFragment inside my tab-fragments, et voila the app crashed everytime I switched back to map-tab.

( The same issue I also would have in case my tab-fragment would inflate any layout containing any other fragment ).

One option is to use the MapView (instead of MapFragment), with some overhead though ( see [MapView Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) as drop-in replacement in the layout.xml, another option is to use support-library up from rev. 11 but then take programmatic approach since nested fragments are neither supported via layout. Or just working around programmatically by explicitely destroying the fragment (like in the answer from Matt / Vidar), btw: same effect is achieved using the MapView (option 1).

But actually, I did not want to loose the map everytime I tab away, that is, I wanted to keep it in memory and cleanup only upon activity close, so I decided to simply hide/show the map while tabbing, see [FragmentTransaction / hide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide%28android.app.Fragment%29)

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still running into this issue, the best way to make sure you don't get this error with a Map in a Tab is to make the Fragment extend `SupportMapFragment` instead of nesting a `SupportMapFragment` inside the Fragment used for the Tab.

I just got this working using a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, with the SupportMapFragment in the third Tab.

Here is the general structure, note there is no need to override the `onCreateView()` method, and there is no need to inflate any layout xml:

```
public class MapTabFragment extends SupportMapFragment 
                                    implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker marker;


    public MapTabFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {

            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        setUpMap();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);


        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                //remove previously placed Marker
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }

                //place marker where user just clicked
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Marker")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Result:

[image]

Here is the full class code that I used to test with, which includes the placeholder Fragment used for the first two Tabs, and the Map Fragment used for the third Tab:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{


    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                case 1:
                    return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                case 2:
                    return MapTabFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        TextView text;

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            text.setText("placeholder");

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class MapTabFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements
            OnMapReadyCallback {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        private Marker marker;


        public static MapTabFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            MapTabFragment fragment = new MapTabFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public MapTabFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            Log.d("MyMap", "onResume");
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

            if (mMap == null) {

                Log.d("MyMap", "setUpMapIfNeeded");

                getMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            Log.d("MyMap", "onMapReady");
            mMap = googleMap;
            setUpMap();
        }

        private void setUpMap() {

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);


            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                    Log.d("MyMap", "MapClick");

                    //remove previously placed Marker
                    if (marker != null) {
                        marker.remove();
                    }

                    //place marker where user just clicked
                    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Marker")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

                    Log.d("MyMap", "MapClick After Add Marker");

                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I respect all the answers but i found this one liner solution:
If n Is the Number of tabs then:

```
 mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(n);
```

Example:
In case mentioned :

```
 mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

View pager implements a queue so, you don't have to let it remove that fragment. onCreateView is called only once.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late to the party but Non of these answer helped me in my case. I was using Google map as **SupportMapFragment** and **PlaceAutocompleteFragment** both in my fragment. As all the answers pointed to the fact that the problem is with SupportMapFragment being the map to be recreated and redrawn.But after digging found out my problem was actually with **PlaceAutocompleteFragment**

So here is the working solution for those who are facing this problem because of **SupportMapFragment** and **SupportMapFragment**

```
 //Global SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
 mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapFragment, mapFragment).commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //Global PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment;


    if (autocompleteFragment == null) {
        autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autoCompleteFragment);

    }
```

And in onDestroyView clear the SupportMapFragment and SupportMapFragment

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();


    if (getActivity() != null) {
        Log.e("res","place dlted");
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.remove(autocompleteFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit(); 
       //Use commitAllowingStateLoss() if getting exception 

        autocompleteFragment = null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested fragments are not currently supported.
Try [Support Package, revision 11](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Downloading).

Answer (score 0):

Have you been trying to reference your custom `MapFragment` class in the layout file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:name="com.nfc.demo.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you please post code for custom map fragment com.nfc.demo.MapFragment

Comment: I am not the author of the code - I just used the code posted in question. You have to ask hermann.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use only Vidar Wahlberg answer, you get error when you open other activity (for example) and back to map. Or in my case open other activity and then from new activity open map again( without use back button).
But when you combine Vidar Wahlberg solution and Matt solution you will have not exceptions.

layout

```
<com.example.ui.layout.MapWrapperLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/map_relative_layout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</<com.example.ui.layout.MapWrapperLayout>
```

Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null){
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
    }
    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_view, null);
        if(view!=null){
            ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.root);
...

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Fragment fragment = this.getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (fragment != null)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this in viewPager and the crash was because any fragment had to have its own tag, duplicate tags or ids for same fragment are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was some bugs in previous App-Compat lib for child Fragment. I tried @Vidar Wahlberg and @Matt's ans they did not work for me. After updating the appcompat library my code run perfectly without any extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

**Things to Note here is your app will crash badly in either of two cases:-**

> 1) In order to reuse fragment with Maps again MapView Fragment must be removed when
>   your fragment showing Maps got replaced with other fragment in onDestroyView callback.
>
> else when you try to inflate same fragment twice *Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment* error will happen.
>
> 2) Secondly you must not mix app.Fragment operations with
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment API operations eg.do not use
>   android.app.FragmentTransaction to remove v4.app.Fragment type 
>   MapView  Fragment. Mixing this will again result into crash from fragment side.

Here is sample code snippet for correct usage of MapView

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.serveroverload.yago.R;

/**
 * @author 663918
 *
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener {
    // Class to do operations on the Map
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        return new HomeFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
        Bundle bdl = getArguments();

        // setuping locatiomanager to perfrom location related operations
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Requesting locationmanager for location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);

        // To get map from MapFragment from layout
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // To change the map type to Satellite
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        // To show our current location in the map with dot
        // googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // To listen action whenever we click on the map
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                /*
                 * LatLng:Class will give us selected position lattigude and
                 * longitude values
                 */
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), latLng.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        changeMapMode(2);

        // googleMap.setSatellite(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        return v;
    }

    private void doZoom() {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(18.520430, 73.856744), 17));
        }
    }

    private void changeMapMode(int mapMode) {

        if (googleMap != null) {
            switch (mapMode) {
            case 0:
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
                break;

            case 1:
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                break;

            case 2:
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                break;

            case 3:
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                break;

            case 4:
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void createMarker(double latitude, double longitude) {
        // double latitude = 17.385044;
        // double longitude = 78.486671;

        // lets place some 10 random markers
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // random latitude and logitude
            double[] randomLocation = createRandLocation(latitude, longitude);

            // Adding a marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1])).title(
                    "Hello Maps " + i);

            Log.e("Random", "> " + randomLocation[0] + ", " + randomLocation[1]);

            // changing marker color
            if (i == 0)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            if (i == 1)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
            if (i == 2)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
            if (i == 3)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            if (i == 4)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            if (i == 5)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
            if (i == 6)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            if (i == 7)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
            if (i == 8)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
            if (i == 9)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));

            googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
            if (i == 9) {
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1]))
                        .zoom(15).build();

                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        }

    }

    /*
     * creating random postion around a location for testing purpose only
     */
    private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

        return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (null != googleMap) {
            // To get lattitude value from location object
            double latti = location.getLatitude();
            // To get longitude value from location object
            double longi = location.getLongitude();

            // To hold lattitude and longitude values
            LatLng position = new LatLng(latti, longi);

            createMarker(latti, longi);

            // Creating object to pass our current location to the map
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            // To store current location in the markeroptions object
            markerOptions.position(position);

            // Zooming to our current location with zoom level 17.0f
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position,
                    17f));

            // adding markeroptions class object to the map to show our current
            // location in the map with help of default marker
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroyView();

        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

        android.app.Fragment fragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (null != fragment) {
            android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity()
                    .getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

}
```

XML

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
```

Result looks like this :-[image]

Hope it will help Somebody.

Answer (score 0):

In this solution you do not need to take static variable;

```
Button nextBtn;

private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    if (mRootView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mRootView.getParent();
        Utility.log(0,"removeView","mRootView not NULL");
        if (parent != null) {
            Utility.log(0, "removeView", "view removeViewed");
            parent.removeAllViews();
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment_layout_one, container, false);//
        } catch (InflateException e) {
    /* map is already there, just return view as it is  */
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return  mRootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.mapView, mapFragment, "mapFragment");
        ft.commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }
    //mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    nextBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utility.replaceSupportFragment(getActivity(),R.id.dummyFragment,dummyFragment_2.class.getSimpleName(),null,new dummyFragment_2());
        }
    });

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an id (android:id="@+id/maps_dialog") for your mapView parent layout. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming here now that's getting this type of error when opening a `Dialog` or other `Fragment` with the Google Places `AutocompleteSupportFragment`, try this one-liner (I don't know how safe this is but it works for me):

`autocompleteFragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(autocompleteFragment).commit();`

before you dismiss/destroy your fragment.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" >
</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

Why don't you insert a map using the MapView object instead of MapFragment ? I am not sure if there is any limitation in MapView,though i found it helpful.

Comment: Sorry i came to know that is the deprecated previous version of Google Maps API