# When inflating fragment which was previously inflated app crashes

Tags: java, android, fragment

The app loads and views `EventFragment.java` which displays a map. When you click another tab fragment it loads that in fine, when you go back to the first tab (the map) it crashes and errors with:

```
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at co.uk.thesomewhere.townpearlfest.EventFragment.onCreateView(EventFragment.java:48)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1264)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #5: Duplicate id 0x7f05000b, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
07-03 14:13:54.640: E/AndroidRuntime(11565):    ... 19 more
07-03 14:13:56.280: I/Process(11565): Sending signal. PID: 11565 SIG: 9
```

So reading that it says the XML file line 5. This is the XML file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/the_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_filerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/magglasswhite"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="filterView" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Which happens to be `<fragment` so.. the error is with the fragment yeah? I dont really know whats going on. Any ideas why this throws an error?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565460/error-opening-supportmapfragment-for-second-time. and this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been fighting with this same issue all day today. I got mine working earlier. Here's what I did: When changing the fragment showing, I first remove the old mapFragment, then do what I normally do when adding new fragments.

```
Fragment oldMapFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
if(oldMapFrag != null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(oldMapFrag).commit();
    manager.popBackStack();
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.content);
    if(container != null)
        container.removeAllViews();
}
```

When I want to view the mapFragment again, I remove the previous fragment then inflate the view with the mapFragment again:

```
Fragment currentFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
if(currentFrag != null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(currentFrag).commit();
    manager.popBackStack();
}
View mapView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.store_finder, container, true);
```

I don't know why `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(oldMapFrag).commit();` works in the first step because you shouldn't be able to remove fragments defined in XML, but this does work for me. I hope it helps.