# SherlockFragment which contains SupportMapFragment does not open second time

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-nested-fragment

In my app there is one SherlockFragmentActivity, whick has 6 fragments. One of these fragments contains map-fragment.

**Problem :**  Now problem is when I launch an app the map loads successfully, but when I goto other fragment and then again try to load map-fragment it doesn't load and gives errors.

I've also tried to remove view, but it is also not working

Here is my code,

```
public class SearchMapFragment extends SherlockFragment implements
        OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener,
        OnInfoWindowClickListener, OnMarkerClickListener, OnMapClickListener {

    private static View mView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mView != null){
            ((ViewGroup)mView.getParent()).removeAllViews();
        }

        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_map, null);   

        if (mMap == null) {

            mf = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_searchMap);

            mMap = mf.getMap();
        }   

        return mView;
    }

}
```

Here is my LogCat,

```
10-03 15:58:08.473: W/dalvikvm(14911): threadid=1: thread exiting with
uncaught exception (group=0x40adc9f0) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class fragment 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at in.vs2.realestate.fragments.SearchMapFragment.onCreateView(SearchMapFragment.java:103)
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #49: Duplicate id 0x7f050075, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment 
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
10-03 15:58:08.503: E/AndroidRuntime(14911):    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly adding `SupportMapFragment` into your fragment.

Please read about [nested fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments).

When nesting fragments remember these things:

- use `getChildFragmentManager`,
- don't add `SupportMapFragment` in xml.

Comment: Thanks MaciejGórski, You are correct....
And I found the exact solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15813151/1931670)