# Google Maps rendering issues in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, android-studio, android-gps

My map home page for my app in android studio isn't 'rendering'. i recive the error "Found cyclical  chain: activity_maps includes activity_maps". Any ideas on fixing this would be much appreciated?

Here's the code for the xml file that won't render:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_maps" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[design screen and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm3V1.png)

Comment: I think this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004048/google-map-inside-a-fragment-with-custom-layout) might help.

Comment: Is the name of your posted RelativeLayout xml file activity_maps?

Comment: yes it is @Andy

Comment: Your fragment definition is referencing the parent layout which contains the fragment - that is the circular reference.  Create a new layout for your fragment and update the above fragment definition to use the new layout.

Comment: Or just get rid of the layout attribute in the fragment definition.

Comment: thanks @Andy you where right