# Inflated Error in Fragment implement SuppportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

hi i have to implement `Google map` in my application. In my application i have 3 tabs in which one of the tab display this Map. but my problem is when i first time go to Map fragment it's working fine but when suddenly go to another tab and then return back to `Map Fragment` my app got crash? with below logcat.

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_bar_gradient"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

[image]

Pleas some one help me on this.

Comment: i think you need to remove `Fragment` on `onDestroyView(....)` event

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to remove `Fragment` in `onDestroyView(....)` event of your `Fragment` like

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroyView ()
    {
        try{
          SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1));
          FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          ft.remove(fragment);
          ft.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
      super.onDestroyView();  
  }
```

And give me feedback on this.

Comment: That's a really bad code. Have you read about [nested fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) and how to properly use them?

Answer (score 0):

As Simple Plan told, you need to remove the map in your onDestroyView.
You can do this like this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map));

        if(mapFragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fM = getFragmentManager();
            fM.beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment).commit();
        }
      super.onDestroyView(); 
    }
```

If this doesn't work try this post: [Error opening SupportMapFragment for second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565460/error-opening-supportmapfragment-for-second-time)

Instead of declaring de SupportMapFragment in layout, do it programatically and be sure you use getChildFragmentMananger instead of the classic getFragmentManager() to create the fragment.

```
mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
             getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map_root, mMapFragment);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Keep this SupportMapFragment mMapFragment as you will need it to retrieve the GoogleMap object:

```
 GoogleMap map = mMapFragment.getMap();
```