# Layout that appears and disappears completely when the application is launched

Tags: android, kotlin, layout

When the application is launched, my layout is displayed for a very short second and then disappears. As a beginner in Kotlin, I don't understand why it produces this result.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="univ.master.kotlin.weather.city.CityFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/city_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="univ.master.kotlin.weather.city.CityFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you set layout in ```CityFragment``` fragment ? if not then first set and try to rebuild project to view preview

Comment: i have added the code of my class below

Comment: Is your activity doing something that removes the fragment? If you say you can see it (`CityFragment`) for a moment then it is working, but something's happening to it. If you use the Layout Inspector in Android Studio (usually in the bottom right corner) you can see exactly what's being displayed on the screen, the view hierarchy etc. Check if the fragment is still there, if it's the right size (not 0dp in width or height), that kind of thing. And yeah that "error" is just asking what layout you want for your preview, just use the one it's suggesting!

Answer (score 1):

It's just a message from the preview window telling you that it can't show a preview for the fragment tag due to not knowing what kind of fragment you'll insert. When you run your actual app, the fragment will render fine.

try to add :

```xml
tools:layout="@android:layout/YOUR_LAYOT"
```

```xml
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/city_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@android:layout/YOUR_LAYOT"
            android:name="univ.master.kotlin.weather.city.CityFragment"/>
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. Can it be from my Kotlin classes?

Comment: You put your layout instead "android:layout/YOUR_LAYOT"

Comment: yes but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for sharing your xml and java code. If you tried everything and still layout is not appring it is just because of android studio is not able to catch you .xml code not to worry.

> You can Select all xml code ctrl+A>ctrl+X>ctrl+V Don't ask me how.

I don't even know how but it works for me. You can also try this because this is the android studio universal rule

> Rebuild project or Clear catch and restart

Hope it helps

Comment: it still doesn't work with your advice

Comment: Here it's example you should try it [https://stackoverflow.com/a/29044108/19674027](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29044108/19674027) you should remove your context code from linear layout. JUST TRY.!!

Comment: I'm starting a kotlin training course and the trainer is doing this. So I did the same thing...

Comment: okay it's you solved that or not