# Inconvertible type error from fragment to SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have a fragment class:

```
public class MyMapFragmentActivity extends Fragment implements LocationListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {
```

Within it I have a SupportMapFragment defined:

```
private SupportMapFragment fragment;
```

I am trying to use the findFragmentById:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

The line

```
fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Despite the 'fragment' being a SupportMapFragment, this is giving inconvertible type error: 
    cannot cast android.app.fragment to com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment !

I'm using fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use compatibility library - use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);` otherwise extend from `android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.fragment`.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing support fragments and the non-support fragment manager.  Use the SupportFragmentManager instead.

Comment: I don't see a "SupportFragmentManager" in any of the dev docs and its not coming up in code hints ?

Comment: Its in the android support library.  Its the code that backports fragments (and a few other things) to 2.x.  Alternatively you can use MapFragment instead of SupportMapFragment, but that will break your app on 2.x.  Basically, to work on 2.x, use only the Support classes.  To work on 4.0+ only, you can use the normal ones.  But never mix the two.

Comment: can you find the supporting reference on Google site ? I can't see it; This answer has 70 pts and is how I've tried to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565460/error-opening-supportmapfragment-for-second-time

Comment: Just google for the exception you've named.  Its caused by mixing support and non-support fragments.  The two can't be mixed.