# When I add MapFragment inside child view of ExpandableListView InflateException occur

Tags: android, expandablelistview, mapfragment

I add map using `MapFragment` inside child view of `ExapndableListview`. When i scroll expanded child then `MapFragment` is loaded, so that `InflateException` occur.

How to add map inside child view of `ExpandableListView` in Android?

Comment: can you able to post your logcat

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f070098, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
 at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4791)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14690441

Comment: @Aline please always copy-paste the error when you're asking the question. It will help you and the people responding to your question.

Comment: Sure @Sufian and Thanks for help Sree