# Android - Unable to destroy activity after finish, caused by IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception, ondestroy, supportmapfragment

I have an activity in my app with 3 fragments. When a button is pushed on the first one, a method is called in the Activity that does some irrelevant stuff and then calls `finish()`.

This triggers `onPause()` on the fragment, which does more irrelevant stuff and then calls `super.onPause()`.

The app then loads the old Activity it came on (logically following the view stack), and suddenly crashes with the following exception when `onDestroyView()` is called on the Fragment:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {be.niteowl.niteowl.debug/be.niteowl.niteowl.views.activities.VenueActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:972)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1327)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1338)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
at be.niteowl.niteowl.views.activities.TrackFragment.onDestroyView(TrackFragment.java:161)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:1665)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:980)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1898)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:324)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onDestroy(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:88)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
... 11 more
```

The error appears to happen when trying to remove a `MapFragment` from the main Fragment. I know that you're not supposed to have fragments within fragments, but the code worked in the past and there's no way around it anyway.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map);
    if (f != null) {
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

I looked around for a fix here on SO already (most notably [getting exception "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa)), but none of them were applicable to my current problem.

Comment: have you actually made sure its running before the savedinstancestate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your activity is being destroyed, your fragments will automatically be destroyed. Hence, there is no need for you to remove them. Simply delete your `onDestroyView()` method.

> I know that you're not supposed to have fragments within fragments, but the code worked in the past and there's no way around it anyway.

First, fragments within fragments are supported via the Android Support package's backport of fragments and the native Android 4.2+ implementation of fragments.

Second, you are not doing fragments within fragments, at least not based on the code shown here. For some reason, your `TrackFragment` is managing another top-level fragment (your `SupportMapFragment`), rather than delegating that work to the activity.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed somewhat of a fix. However, now I have issues when going away to a 3rd tab and then going back:

    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #96: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
        ... (too long for this comment)

Comment: @Vindicator: Perhaps open a new StackOverflow question, where you can show the entire stack trace and the relevant XML and Java code.

Comment: @Vindicator this seems to fix the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17422251/732489

Answer (score 20):

The following code worked for me. It is placed in the fragment that calls the map fragment

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
    if (f.isResumed()){ 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: thanks man, the crash was when I was trying to close the app and your code fix it

Comment: f.isResumed() worked for me too, i was just using f != null (which I think shoud be in your code as well), thanks a lot!

Comment: finally! did it for me too!

Answer (score 0):

Committing transactions in **OnPostResume()** callback fixed the issue for me. Thanks to following blogpost http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

```
@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    // Commit your transactions here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your activity is destroyed which causes the fragments to be destroyed, .commit() cannot be handled.

Remove getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove().commit().

Try handling in onBackPressed(), which I did for my application

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using below code in the activity:

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try{
            super.onDestroy();
        }catch (NullPointerException e){

        }
    }
```