# How Would I Add A View/Fragment that Runs Another Activity?

Tags: android

I am interested in creating some kind of View or Fragment that takes up a small amount (~33%) of the current View.  This overlayed View will use the camera as input.  I think this is analogous to the YouTube app's small video playing in the corner.

I have a crude sketch of what I want (below).  I don't need a full writeup, just a starting point.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean `a fragment running another activity`?

Comment: Currently, I use an intent to launch another activity that takes the entire screen and then returns.  If it's possible, I'd like to make it only show as an overlay.  I can perhaps use another method to invoke the View, but I'd like the overlay effect.

Comment: I guess you can do this with `Fragment`s instead of another `Activity` and hosting it in `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is the good way for it, but you can try with a `FrameLayout` to host a `Fragment` and make the `FrameLayout` with a background transparent (if you don't know what is [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html), in few words it serves to overlap views. I writed [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683433/2668136) on this). The layout of your `Parent Activity` ([FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)) may be something like this:

```
<FrameLayout 
     android:id="@+id/FragmentContainer"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

     <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:text="I'm a text of the content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the `Fragment` may be as below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ReaderEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="I'm a text in a fragment" >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then when you initialise your `Fragment` in the `FrameLayout`, you set **hide()** and **show()** methods for display it. For this, use `FragmentSupportManager` in your `FragmentActivity` and **add()** or **replace()** methods like the example below:

```
// Initialize your fragment: 

FragmentTransaction mTransaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment mFrag = new MyFragment(); // call your Fragment Class
mTransaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer, mFrag, null).hide(mFrag).commit(); // add to the Container (FrameLayout) and hide it
// don't forget to commit at the end of every FragmentTransaction

// To display your fragment: 

FragmentTransaction mTranDisplay = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mTranDisplay.show(mFrag).addToBackStack(null).commit(); // pass the Fragment to show + add the BackStack method (when the user press back button, the Fragment disappears without quit the Activity)
mTranDisplay.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, 0, 0, R.anim.slide_out); // you can make an animation to the BackStack method, here it's a slide in/out from top to bottom
```

I think there is a proper way to do this. Maybe you can check [this library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) and see, break, rebuild,... the code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will take a look at this and report back.