# Fragment doesn't work using fragment tag, works in framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-framelayout

Fragment doesn't work when using fragment tag in XML layout. But, after replace fragment tag to Framelayout it works fine without making any change in my code.

When i use the code below fragment doesn't change/work.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:name="com.example.user.example.MyFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnPressMe"
    />
```

But, when i replace the above code with the code below it changes/works.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnPressMe">
</FrameLayout>
```

Java code:

```
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: both have same Id .... ??

Comment: I do comment one at a time, this is just to show the code.

Comment: use different id...for same kind of tags'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453530/android-when-why-should-i-use-framelayout-instead-of-fragment

Comment: Koutuk, As I said i do remove fragment when i use framelayout. I am just showing the code above. Please don't get confused.

Comment: you must provide container to fragment tag .... fragment will not replace itself Container is required to do such replace ...\

Comment: Please explain what "does not work" means in this case.

Comment: @koutuk You are right that we must provide container to fragment tag, but, the Lineralayout in which the fragment is located is also a container.

Comment: right i have added some code as answer pls go through ...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to infalte to another fragment you must use
 getChildFragmentManager() instead of  getFragmentManager()

```
FragmentManager fobject = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fobject .beginTransaction();
fragment_container= fobject .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

if (fragment_container!= null) {
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, yournewfragment);
transaction.commit();
}
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I am using Api 23 and there is no function like getChildFragmentManager()