# Null pointer on inflated view when loading for the second time a google map fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm using a DrawerLayout and when I load for the second time a google map fragment the exception will be caught as expected; however, further in the same method when I try

```
Button btnShowList = (Button) ui.findViewById(R.id.btnShowList);
```

and I get a null pointer exception. I guess that's because `ui` was not assigned any value.

How can I deal with this?

**Page2.java:**

```
public class Page2 extends Fragment {

    View ui;
    final String TAG = "POPE";
    final int CODIGO_DE_RESULTADO_1 = 1; // Es para usarlo en onActivityResult();

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public Page2(){
        // Este es el constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (ui != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) ui.getParent();
            if (parent != null){
                parent.removeView(ui);
            }
        }

        try {
            ui = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page2,container,false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
            Log.i(TAG,"HERE COMES THE STACK TRACE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        mMap = ((MapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);     
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        Button btnShowList = (Button) ui.findViewById(R.id.btnShowList);
        btnShowList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showFileslist();
            }
        });

        return ui;

    }
}
```

**activity_page2.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShowList"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Load points" />
```

**Log:**

```
07-08 22:17:44.203: I/POPE(11859): HERE COMES THE STACK TRACE
07-08 22:17:44.213: W/System.err(11859): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
07-08 22:17:44.213: W/System.err(11859):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
07-08 22:17:44.213: W/System.err(11859):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
07-08 22:17:44.213: W/System.err(11859):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
07-08 22:17:44.213: W/System.err(11859):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-08 22:17:44.213: W/System.err(11859):    at com.jorgeandresserrano.gpstools.Page2.onCreateView(Page2.java:52)
07-08 22:17:44.213: W/System.err(11859):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
07-08 22:17:44.213: W/System.err(11859):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
07-08 22:17:44.213: W/System.err(11859):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
07-08 22:17:44.213: W/System.err(11859):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-08 22:17:44.213: W/System.err(11859):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f05003f, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
07-08 22:17:44.223: W/System.err(11859):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4863)
07-08 22:17:44.233: W/System.err(11859):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
07-08 22:17:44.233: W/System.err(11859):    ... 19 more
07-08 22:17:44.233: D/AndroidRuntime(11859): Shutting down VM
07-08 22:17:44.233: W/dalvikvm(11859): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410feac8)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at com.myname.myapp.Page2.onCreateView(Page2.java:66)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-08 22:17:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Line 66 is:**

```
Button btnShowList = (Button) ui.findViewById(R.id.btnShowList);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem can be resolved by removing the map fragment in the onDestroyView() method just before leaving. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (f != null){ 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
}
```

This post explains this more in detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484640/2422833

Comment: the best solution... ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `OnResume` for your fragment. Make a reference to your ui. And OnResume check again that ui object is null or not then inflate it again. Since it called 2nd time there possibility that it don't go through your onCreateView again.

Comment: onCreateView() is called first than onResume(), so the error happens before onResume() has any chance of interacting. By the way, I'm using a DrawerLayout

Comment: Normally the firstime onCreateView was called. After that if the Fragment was not destroyed then when it is called 2nd time onCreateView would not be triggered anymore (since the View already be inflated). Just messing around like release all View references OnPause or resume all View by OnResume. From my point of view it's weird for OnCreateView was called 2nd time if the Fragment was inflated and you did not dispose of the Activity which content the fragment sush as finish()

Comment: I think it has to do with the management of the fragment but not really sure what's happening. It keeps calling onCreateView(). Probably the way fragments are handled by a DrawerLayout?

Comment: reading your stactrace exception happen first at line 52 com.jorgeandresserrano.gpstools.Page2.onCreateView ... on your IDE which code was there in that line ?