# Calling map fragment second time getting error

Tags: android, android-fragments, dictionary

I'm using map in fragment. First time its loading well but when I call it second getting error -

```
: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
```

xml code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapfragment"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

java code -

```
   map = ((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment)).getMap();
```

referred many questions on stack tried below code also but not working -

```
public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView(); 
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment));   
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

**Using temporary Solutions -**

I'm restarting fragment activity by passing map fragment integer value so that after opening fragment activity it will load map fragment directly.

Comment: What doing in the second time? please post second time related code.

Comment: The posted code is related only.i'm doing this all in fragment.1st time i opened map fragment..then after another fragment when i'm trying to open map fragment getting this error

Comment: Have you seen these answers??? [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14690441/3884250) and [**Here - Preffered Solution**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17560504/3884250)

Comment: @NadeemIqbal is i have already mention it that i have referred many questions on stack. Please read my question again. I have done that part

Comment: I got this error too. I could fix it only instantiating the Fragment each time it was replaced. None of solutions that I found in SO didn't work to me.

Comment: @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
  super.onDestroyView();

  locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

  android.app.Fragment fragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  if (null != fragment) {
   android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity()
     .getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.remove(fragment);
   ft.commit();
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
     />
```

Refer this link [for Duplicate id.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094482/duplicated-id-with-fragment/20096988#20096988) it  contains same error that you are getting and it worked for me ,Just use `android:name` attribute instead of `class` attriute.