# Google maps nullpointer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I get a nullpointer everytime I try to instance the map.

I found a lot of articles about it but that didn't work.
The map needs to exist in another fragment.

This is my code:

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {

private Contact contact = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    contact = Shared.dbRepo.contactsRepository.getFirst();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_price, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.title(contact.getTitle());
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
    markerOptions.position(getLocation(contact.getAddress()));
    map.addMarker(markerOptions);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
    mainActivity.showActionBar();
}

private LatLng getLocation(String strAddress) {
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    List<Address> address;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);

        if (address == null) {
            Address location = address.get(0);

            return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/contact_address" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_contact_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
            android:autoLink="map"
            android:text="@string/opening_hours" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:autoLink="email"
            android:text="@string/contact_email" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_contact_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
            android:text="@string/opening_hours" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/contact_telephone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_contact_telephone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
            android:autoLink="phone"
            android:text="@string/opening_hours" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/contact_website" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_contact_website"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/opening_hours" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:
This is the exception I get:

```
05-20 16:32:18.295    6663-6663/be.appmax.twentebad.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: be.appmax.twentebad.app, PID: 6663
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at be.appmax.twentebad.app.fragments.ContactFragment.onViewCreated(ContactFragment.java:48)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:952)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is line 48:

```
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: what is line no 50???

Comment: Added line 50 to the post

Comment: isGooglePlayServicesAvailable?

Comment: can you please try after copying the whole contents in `onViewCreated()` to `onCreateView()`..please..

Comment: Have a try and tell me what the output is...

Comment: Output still the same

Answer (score 1):

if you are using

```
mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
```

use

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

you are using `SupportMapFragment` in Java class and you have used `MapFragment` in your xml file..That is why the `NullPointerException` is raised...

**EDIT**

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: I fixed that but I added the exception that I now get.

Comment: I added the whole code to the post and also edited the exception

Comment: @Ghost is the map fragment in your XML the only item in it? If so I can post a more detailed answer as opposed to the one below. However I don't understand why you are using getActivity().

Comment: @Android-converter I added the full XML to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line:

```
mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getExtendedMap();
```

Basically adding: .getExtendedMap(); at the end on your fragment line

EDIT:
If your xml is this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Then your code in onViewCreated should be:

```
mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getExtendedMap();
```

I have just created an example app myself to check and it works for me. When you get to (R.id.map)). there will not be a drop down option for getExtendedMap();

Comment: From memory when using SupportMapFragment you have to use getExtendedMap and not getMap, thats what I have in my app, I had issues with mine before and getExtendedMap fixed it for me

Comment: I tried getExtendedMap() but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Cannot Resolve getExtendedMap()

Comment: you have imported com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment in your class file?

Comment: At the top of your class you should be extending FragmentActivity not just fragment

Comment: Yea but then it is an Activity and not a fragment anymore. I need the fragment to go in another FragmentActivity

Comment: I would follow this post and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206615/how-to-use-google-map-v2-inside-fragment in that case as the solution(s) seem to be there

Answer (score -1):

public class MapFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
GoogleMap map;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);
    googleMapMark();


}

private void googleMapMark() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).getMap();
        Double lng = null, lat = null;

        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();

    if(map!=null){

        if(b!=null)
        {
            lat=b.getDouble("lat");
            Log.v("latitude in MapFragmentActivity","Latitude : " + lat);

            lng=b.getDouble("longitude");
            Log.v("longitude in MapFragmentActivity","Latitude : " + lng);
        }else
        {
            lat=23.0300;
            lng=72.5800;
            Log.v("Bundle is Null","Default lat long is set");
        }

        final LatLng mapPin = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        System.out.println("New Latitude:::-" + lat);
        System.out.println("New Longtitude:::-" + lng);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(mapPin)
                .title("Latitude::-" + lat)
                .snippet("Longtitude::-" + lng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.malls)));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mapPin, 15));
        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am using a fragment like I said so I cannot do the following