# inflater.inflate results in NullPointerException when called for the second time

Tags: android, tabs, nullpointerexception, google-maps-api-2

I have the following layout. Lets call it mapFragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/fragmentId"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:orientation="vertical">

   <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/mapIdfragmentId"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</fragment>
```

It is used in a tab view. This is the first tab of 3. When loading the tab view this is the first tab that is loaded. No problems here. If I go to the second tab and then go back - again I have no problems. But if I go to the third tab and try to go back (no matter if the second or first tab) Then I have a NPE in the first tab's onCreate method

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapFragment, container, false);
     return v;
   }
```

The NPE happens at the second line - View v = ....
The root cause of the exception is

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f040005, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
 E/AndroidRuntime(17423):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4722)
```

I'm using the Sherlock library and the device is running at Android v2.2.2

PS: the suggested solution here - [Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi) fixes the problem but after that the map is totally frozen :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are on wrong track**

**remove this from xml**

```
 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/mapIdfragmentId"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Because this Fragment is containing map itself Thats why it throwing duplication error**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/fragmentId"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:orientation="vertical">
</fragment>
```

Comment: oh my god you are trying to inflate fragment inside the fragment

Comment: am.. the MapView tag, not tab :) My bad

Comment: sorry dude android not support nested fragment in xml. you have to push fragment runtime.

Comment: @MihailYordanov http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html. check the note under nested fragments

Comment: Actually your comment helped. I didn't understand it at first but now its working great

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapFragment, container, false);
 return v;
}
```

Your are not returning the view inflated.

Also if you are using map api v1 its deprecated. Switch to api v2

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: you don't need that and your returning a view that you inflated

Comment: Editted the post since it seems I didnt explain the problem right