# duplicated id with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, navigation-drawer, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to applicate drawernavigation (my first fragment is a map & the others are just some fragments with simple layouts).So it runs fine & I can navigate between my fragments but when I return to the first fragment which is a map I got a  crash

**logcat:**

```
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at challenge.arabe.taxitaxi.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:48)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f05000c, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4253)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
11-20 11:03:27.306: E/AndroidRuntime(13787):    ... 18 more
```

I think this the most impportant:

```
Duplicate id 0x7f05000c, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

so this is my code:
**LoginScreen:a fragmentActivity which make all call for the fragment**

```
public class LoginScreen extends FragmentActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;



MapFragment mMap;
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);




          int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
            if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                        // what you want to do
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "good connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          //  setUpMapIfNeeded();
           // addTwitterMarq();

            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

            // load slide menu items
            navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

            // nav drawer icons from resources
            navMenuIcons = getResources()
                    .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

            navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

            // adding nav drawer items to array
            // Home
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
            // Find People
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
            // Photos
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
            // Communities, Will add a counter here
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
            // Pages
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
            // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


            // Recycle the typed array
            navMenuIcons.recycle();

            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

            // setting the nav drawer list adapter
            adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    navDrawerItems);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

            // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                    R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                    R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
            ) {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // on first time display view for first nav item
                displayView(0);
            }


    }


    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }





    private void addTwitterMarq() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    LatLng pos = new LatLng(48.85078, 2.34440);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .title("Twitter")
             .snippet("Twitter HQ")
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
             .position(pos)          
          );


    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (googleMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);       

            if (googleMap != null) {
               // setUpMap();
                drawTestJunk();

            }
        }
    }

    private void drawTestJunk() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UiSettings settings = googleMap.getUiSettings();

        settings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        settings.setCompassEnabled(true);
        settings.setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);

        settings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        CameraUpdate camUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(45.53, -73.59), 14);
        googleMap.moveCamera(camUpdate);



        /**
         * "Markers" lesson
         */
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(45.538490,-73.598480))
        .title("Hello world")
        .snippet("what does a snippet look like?")
        .draggable(true)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                );
        /**
         * skipping other "Marker" lessons, to move on to Lines, Polygons, and Circles.
         * Topic list for later study:
         * - Customized info windows
         * - Marker click events
         * - Marker drag events
         * - Info window click events
         */


        /**
         * "Lines, Polygons, and Circles" lesson
         */

        // LINE
        PolylineOptions route = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(45.538451240403596, -73.59851807077722) )
        .add(new LatLng(45.5390432, -73.5997465) )
        .add(new LatLng(45.5387234, -73.6000517) )
        .add(new LatLng(45.5389376, -73.6005275) )
        .color(Color.GREEN)
        ;


        Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(route);
        //you can also call PolylineOptions.addAll(Iterable<LatLng>) if the points are already in a list


        // POLYGON
        ArrayList<LatLng> hole= new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        hole.add(new LatLng(45.5275, -73.5925));
        hole.add(new LatLng(45.5225, -73.5925));
        hole.add(new LatLng(45.5225, -73.5975));
        hole.add(new LatLng(45.5275, -73.5975));

        PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(45.53, -73.59),
                new LatLng(45.52, -73.59),
                new LatLng(45.52, -73.60),
                new LatLng(45.53, -73.60),
                new LatLng(45.53, -73.59))
                .addHole(hole)
                .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                .fillColor(Color.BLUE);

        Polygon polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);

        // And sure, why not, a CIRCLE
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
        .center(new LatLng(45.525, -73.595))
        .radius(100);

        Circle circle = googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and this is my main layout for the fragmentActivity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   </FrameLayout>

    <!--     

<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

     -->

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is the xml layout of the mapfragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the mapfragment code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


      int mCurrentPosition = -1;
MapFragment mMap;
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
            }
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
//        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
//        if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
//                    // what you want to do
//          //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "good connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        }

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        addTwitterMarq();
        return rootView;
    }




    private void addTwitterMarq() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    LatLng pos = new LatLng(48.85078, 2.34440);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .title("Twitter")
             .snippet("Twitter HQ")
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
             .position(pos)          
          );


    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (googleMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);       

            if (googleMap != null) {
               // setUpMap();
                drawTestJunk();

            }
        }
    }

    private void drawTestJunk() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UiSettings settings = googleMap.getUiSettings();

        settings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        settings.setCompassEnabled(true);
        settings.setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);

        settings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        CameraUpdate camUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(45.53, -73.59), 14);
        googleMap.moveCamera(camUpdate);



        /**
         * "Markers" lesson
         */
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(45.538490,-73.598480))
        .title("Hello world")
        .snippet("what does a snippet look like?")
        .draggable(true)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                );
        /**
         * skipping other "Marker" lessons, to move on to Lines, Polygons, and Circles.
         * Topic list for later study:
         * - Customized info windows
         * - Marker click events
         * - Marker drag events
         * - Info window click events
         */


        /**
         * "Lines, Polygons, and Circles" lesson
         */

        // LINE
        PolylineOptions route = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(45.538451240403596, -73.59851807077722) )
        .add(new LatLng(45.5390432, -73.5997465) )
        .add(new LatLng(45.5387234, -73.6000517) )
        .add(new LatLng(45.5389376, -73.6005275) )
        .color(Color.GREEN)
        ;


        Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(route);
        //you can also call PolylineOptions.addAll(Iterable<LatLng>) if the points are already in a list


        // POLYGON
        ArrayList<LatLng> hole= new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        hole.add(new LatLng(45.5275, -73.5925));
        hole.add(new LatLng(45.5225, -73.5925));
        hole.add(new LatLng(45.5225, -73.5975));
        hole.add(new LatLng(45.5275, -73.5975));

        PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(45.53, -73.59),
                new LatLng(45.52, -73.59),
                new LatLng(45.52, -73.60),
                new LatLng(45.53, -73.60),
                new LatLng(45.53, -73.59))
                .addHole(hole)
                .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                .fillColor(Color.BLUE);

        Polygon polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);

        // And sure, why not, a CIRCLE
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
        .center(new LatLng(45.525, -73.595))
        .radius(100);

        Circle circle = googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

    }
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        //setUpMapIfNeeded();
        //addTwitterMarq();
    }

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);

}
public void updateArticleView(int position) {
    mCurrentPosition = position;
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
     Bundle args = getArguments();
     if (args != null) {
         // Set article based on argument passed in
         updateArticleView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
     } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
         // Set article based on saved instance state defined during onCreateView
         updateArticleView(mCurrentPosition);
     }
}
}
```

I think that the problem is located in onResume & onCreateView methods!!
 Hope that you'll help me 
thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

use this

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
         />
```

and override method `onDestroyView()` and Just put this code in `onDestroyView()`

```
public void onDestroyView() 
 {
    super.onDestroyView(); 
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and while it worked at first; when I turned the device into landscape/portrait I got an IllegalStateException when I tried to commit(). There are other posts on SO talking about this; you can't commit after an onStop or onSaveInstanceState has been called on the fragment.

Comment: you can use commitAllowingStateLoss() method insted of commit and make sure you have given attributes to your activity android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" in android manifiest file

Answer (score 13):

Try to reuse/recycle your layout.
I am running into "duplicate id" when using a map fragment.
So in **onCreateView** instead of

```
final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
```

i am using

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
   public YourFragment(){}
   ...
   private static View rootView;
   ...


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    if (rootView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        /* map is already there, just return view as it is  */
    }
```

Comment: This answer is far better. Using the selected answer's method I was crashing my app due to IllegalStateExceptions. Attempting to commit() after onStop or after onSaveInstanceState will trigger this. The easiest way to see this is turn your phone into portrait/landscape.

Comment: Better answer than the accepted one. This one keeps the previous state of the fragment. Thank you very much, bro.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try to retrieve old Fragments instance instead of recreating it each time a drawer item is selected. In your displayView method of LoginScreen Activity, you have to do something like that in the switch:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
String title = getResources().getString(SOME_FRAGMENT_TITLE);
switch (position) {
case 1:
   fragment = (YourFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(title);
   if (fragment == null) fragment = new YourFragment();
   break;
 }
```