# using maps in fragment in sliding drawer ,want to replace old maps when again come to maps from other fragment

Tags: android, maps, fragment, sliding, drawer

code for `fragment` of `maps`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fine_tech, container, false);



    return rootView;
}
    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{

    if (fragment != null) {

         fragment =  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
           FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           ft.remove(fragment);
           ft.commit();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     Thread.interrupted();

}
```

Comment: Used `onDestroyView()` instead of `onDestroy()`

Comment: @MD May be `onPause()` instead of `onDestroyView()`

Comment: @MD it crashes when i come back to maps from another fragment.now i used ondestroyview()  ..can we do some change in oncreateview

Comment: @MD it worked thanks ...but now i have one more problem ..app crashes when i clicked twice on map option ..i searched it lot ..but i did,t get a solution ..i m using maps in fragment in sliding drawer

Comment: @SMR it worked thanks ...but now i have one more problem ..app crashes when i clicked twice on map option ..i searched it lot ..but i did,t get a solution ..i m using maps in fragment in sliding drawer

Comment: @DeepSingh post a new question with detailed description of the problem

Comment: @SMR problem is that ...i m using a sliding drawer .in the sliding drawer there is no of fragments ..there is one fragment of map ..now if i clicked twice on the sliding drawer on map fragment option ..map got crash ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094482/duplicated-id-with-fragment         plz check this link ,same kind of code i m using .. @SMR

Comment: @SMR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523014/how-to-implement-signout-functionality-in-integration-in-social-auth-in-android ..can u help me in this