# how to implement signout functionality for Facebook integration in social-auth for android

Tags: integration, socialauth

I am using social auth library for sharing and login with social media in android app.  I have logged in and authorize successfully with facebook.

```
class SignUp extends Activity {
    SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        adapter.authorize(SignUp.this, Provider.FACEBOOK);}
```

but I don't know how to signout from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
adapter.signOut(getApplicationContext(), Provider.FACEBOOK.toString());
```

Comment: thanks ..man @ojonugwa ochalifu  can i use this ,instead of getActivity(). bcz its shows error on getActivity() and i m not using fragment ..

Comment: Yes, that's why I changed it to `getApplicationContext()`, if you have  context already in the method you are using it, just pass that instead.

Comment: can u tell me one more thing that how we can get access token from this ..@ojonugwa ochalifu