# GoogleMap v2 - random crashing onResume()

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm having an app which is using google map api v2 and it is working very well without any errors.When I try to restart the app after starting, it works fine but if I leave it minimized (with pressing the home button for example) when I try to start it again after 1-2 hours the app crashes. That is very annoing and I still can't catch that error.

I think that my app is storing something into the device memory which is using after resuming but it is destroied.

Any ideas?
And btw sorry for my bad english (:

Edit: [Here is a link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5s1k40CwNLqNUdSSGlVcGs3eEU/edit) for my log. 
[That is my java class](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5s1k40CwNLqMW9fQ0pyQmIwT1U/edit).
The log is showing at line 152 of my class.

Comment: Please, post your activity's code and if possible - crash log

Comment: Ok, maybe this can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi

Comment: Yes, I just saw it too after searching for that "Duplicate id" where was the real problem ;)
Thanks