# IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed - when app is trying to show DialogFragment once more time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, illegalstateexception

**I have found a lot of similar questions on the stackoverflow but their solutions don't work in my case. They are connected with `onSaveInstanceState` method and the Support Library especially.**

I have `Activity` which runs on one event this code:

```
MyDialogFragment.showMyDialog(name, this, this);
```

`name` parameter is the String object. Second parameter (`this`) is the just `Activity` class object and the third one (also `this`) is the simple interface. This my `Activity` implements this interface. `showMyDialog()` is of course static method. This is it body:

```
MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment(listener, "Hello " + name);
fragment.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");
```

This is working good at the first try. But at the second I am getting this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 20759
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1345)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:597)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:575)
        at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:230)
        at com.example.myapp.view.dialog.MyDialogFragment.showMyDialog(MyDialogFragment.java:41)
        at com.example.myapp.MyActivity.showMyDialog(MyActivity.java:208)
        at com.example.myapp.MyActivity.onEvent(MyActivity.java:232)
        at com.example.myapp.MyActivity.handleMessage(MyActivity.java:89)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In general this is the steps to reproduce my exception:

1. Enter `Activity` - event is received so `MyDialogFragment` is shown.
2. Dismiss dialog by negative button.
3. Enter `Activity` once more time - `MyDialogFragment` is shown again.
4. Type some code to the EditText.
5. At this moment validation take some time. Connecting with server etc. And the negative result is returned. So it is need to show `MyDialogFragment` once more. But at this moment I am getting exception.

However, when I skip the second point and start to typing wrong code for validation, `MyDialogFragment` will be shown without any issue. Strange behaviour.

I have tried with non-static method, `setRetainInstance(true)` and also `commitAllowingStateLoss`. But there was no difference.

Comment: Can you post your Dialog's showMyDialog method?

Comment: @kupsef the body of this method I have posted in my question. This is only two lines of code as you can see.

Comment: If you use the support library you must call getSupportFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager. Furthermore, if you are inside a fragment, you have to use getChildFragmentManager.

Comment: @MattiaFranchetto thanks for your suggestion but I am not using support library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a bit odd - or maybe just a bug in this Android functionality. I have added block `try catch` to catch throwing exception in this way:

```
MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment(listener, "Hello " + name);
try {
    fragment.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And of course exception is still throwing (and catching at this moment) and what is interesting my dialog fragment is recreating in correct way and user can interact with it.

Comment: I just was trying to show a dialog after asyncktask was complete but sometimes the user closed the activity before and this code solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In the method `showMyDialog()` first try :

```
MyDialogFragment fragment = activity.findFragmentByTag("myDialog");
```

if `(fragment == null)`, then initialize :

```
MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment(listener, "Hello " + name);
```

else show it :

```
fragment.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");
```

UPDATE :

```
void showMyDialog() {
    MyDialogFragment fragment = activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myDialog");
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new MyDialogFragment(listener, "Hello " + name);
    }
    fragment.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");
}
```

Comment: you mean `activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myDialog")`?

Comment: But your answer unfortunately is not working in my case. And in additition `fragment.show()` method can not be in else block.

Comment: Yes, I have used your answer in the way you have updated. But it changes nothing.

Answer (score 4):

(For API 17 and up)

In case anyone is still having this problem (or even related with a transaction's `commit()` method) I just added a check before it:

```
private showFragment() {
    if (isDestroyed()) {
        return;
    }

    // Else do whatever transaction...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the below line

```
MyDialogFragment.showMyDialog(name, this, this);
```

to

```
MyDialogFragment.showMyDialog(name, **"Activity class name.this"**, this);
```

Comment: but `showMyDialog()` method needs `Activity` object as a second argument, no `String`...

Comment: np you are getting me wrong you dont have to change it to string.

just change this to ActivityName.this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while I was trying to add a `SupportMapFragment` within a `DialogFragment`. I could fix this error by using `getChildFramentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`, as suggested by the API when using nested fragments:

```
public class GpsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private static final String MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG = "MAP_FRAGMENT";


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gps_postition_dialog, container, false);
        // ...

        // dynamically create the map fragment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950)
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            if (!getActivity().isFinishing()) {
                mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.mapFrame, mapFragment, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                ft.commit();
                fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
            }
        }

        return view;
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mapFragment != null)
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment).commit();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```