# App crash, Duplicate id, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

Basically the app crash when I open one fragment after a period of inactivity, or Having left it in the background, or after unlocking the phone with the app open.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi) answer, but honestly I could not solve it, if anyone could correct me specifically my code and explain it, I'll be grateful

**LogCat:**

```
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.TheX.fadubusca.Fragment4.onCreateView(Fragment4.java:37)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f050054, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
07-06 15:32:25.992: E/AndroidRuntime(4155):     ... 19 more
```

I have multiple mapfragment, are put one, but the problem is with any of the 21 who i have

**Fragment.java:**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Fragment0 extends SherlockFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment0, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

final LatLng Initial = new LatLng(-34.673009, -58.474111);
final LatLng FADU = new LatLng(-34.542163, -58.443716);



GoogleMap googlemap;

    googlemap  = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map0)).getMap();

    googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Initial, 10);
    googlemap.animateCamera(update);


    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(FADU).title("FADU").snippet("Facultad de Arquitectura, Diseño y Urbanismo")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

    }

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

 }
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {

    super.onDestroyView(); 
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map0));  
    if (fragment != null){
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .remove(fragment)
    .commit();          
    }
}
```

**fragment.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f050054, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragmen

Comment: i know that , but i have 21 mapfragments, and all work perfectly when I switch between them, but I have this problem only after a period of inactivity, or Having left it in the background, or after unlocking the phone with the app open. 

You know any solution ?