# Google Map Fragment + FragmentPagerAdapter refuse to coordinate

Tags: android, android-fragments

Well I have a simple scenario here .

**Case**

1) A FragmentStateAdapter that would house three fragments

```
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment=new LocationFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment=new CongestFrag();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment=new SubcribedFrag();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

The location Fragment as the name implies , would house a google map fragment . The XML for this would be

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/off_white"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_title"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fragments_title_view_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fragments_title_view_height"
    android:text="@string/location_fragment_title" 
    android:textSize="@dimen/fragments_title_text_size"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>

<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Similarly the other fragments contain for example just one textviews.

**The issue**

We all know that when we proceed or retreat in the list of fragments , the viewpager niftly destroys and recreates fragments . THIS IS FINE for me . I do not wish to use *setOffscreenPageLimit* to force the fragments to stay in memory .

The problem is with the LocationFragment. The application starts with LocationFragment , which properly displays a map . This is how I proceed then

LocationFragment-->CongestFrag-->SubcribedFrag

Everything works fine . Now when I come in reverse .

SubscribedFrag->CongestFrag . The program breakpoint for OnCreateView for LocationFragment hits and it gives this stack trace

```
10-12 15:26:21.096: E/AndroidRuntime(17122): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #16: Duplicate id 0x7f060010, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

This is the code that breaks (LocationFragment.java), when I come towards LocationFragment from the bottom of the fragment list

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mFragmentView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_fragment, container, false);

                //code breaks above 

     mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Globals.LocationFragment.DEFAULT_LAT, Globals.LocationFragment.DEFAULT_LONG)).title("Marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Globals.LocationFragment.DEFAULT_LAT, Globals.LocationFragment.DEFAULT_LONG), 8.0f));

    /*Just a container to keep the width and height . See usage*/
    mSize = new Point();


    initProperties();
    initControls();
    return mFragmentView;
}
```

**Speculation**
It seems that the fragment is previously not properly destroyed , and android is inflating the same view twice . But that doesn't make sense ofcourse . Please aid me in this .

Thanks

Comment: "We all know that when we proceed or retreat in the list of fragments , the viewpager niftly destroys and recreates fragments" -- no, it does not. `ViewPager` knows absolutely nothing about fragments. `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` know about fragments, and only the latter will destroy and recreate those fragments based upon page navigation. I would not expect it to destroy anything with only three pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi)

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated  . I found a similar post already with numerous solutions . Should have researched better . If it interests anyone , here is the link "[Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-android)"