# Error inflating class fragment: Duplicate id , tag null, or parent id with another fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to make an app in which when user clicks on item in ListView, the GoogleMaps is displayed.

I have tried following code:

**ShowPlacesActivity.java**

```
public class ShowPlaceActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_place);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container_showplaces, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        getActionBar().setSubtitle(getString(R.string.activity_showplaces_subtitle));
    }

}
```

**activity_show_place.xml**

```
<FrameLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container_showplaces"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.krupal.rememberthisplace.ShowPlaceActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

**fragment_show_place.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_places"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      />


</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_maps.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mymap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to show maps on listview's item click...so, I have implemented two fragments as follows:

In **PlaceholderFragment.java**, I have set `onitemclicklistener` as:

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_place, container, false);



            final MySqliteHelper db = new MySqliteHelper(getActivity().getBaseContext());


            listview_places = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_places);

            final PlacesAdapter places_adapter = new PlacesAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.listview_item_row,places);


            listview_places.setAdapter(places_adapter);


            listview_places.setLongClickable(true);

            listview_places.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position,long id) {
                    Place place = places_adapter.getItem(position);
                    String dbvaluename = place.getname();

                  Place selectedplace =  db.getPlace(dbvaluename);


                    dblatitude = selectedplace.getlatitude();

                    dblongitude = selectedplace.getlongitude();


                    dbplacename = place.getname();

                   maps = new MapsFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putDouble("dbplacename",dblatitude);
                    bundle.putDouble("dbplacename",dblongitude);
                    bundle.putString("dbplacename",dbplacename);
                   maps.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                    ft.replace(R.id.container_showplaces,maps);

                    ft.addToBackStack(null);

                    ft.commit();

                }



        });
}
}
```

and In **MapsFragment.java**, I have shown maps as:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);


    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

When I click first time on ListView's item, it shows the Map...Then, when I select another item, it crashes:

**Logcat log:**

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
>   inflating class fragment
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>           at com.krupal.rememberthisplace.MapsFragment.onCreateView(MapsFragment.java:40)
>           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
>           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
>           at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
>           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
>           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate
>   id 0x7f0b001e, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment
>   for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
>           at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4248)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>               at com.krupal.rememberthisplace.MapsFragment.onCreateView(MapsFragment.java:40)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
>               at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**EDIT:** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi?rq=1) soloution didn't work for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I solved it now!

The another solution is linked answer worked for me well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484640/3960528

As explained there, I added `onDestroyView()` in `fragment that contains maps.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                         .findFragmentById(R.id.mymap);
    if (f != null) 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
}
```

Comment: Man, it's ****ing 3 AM in the morning and I am so damn stupid to remove the added fragments. Thanks, mate. Cheers...

Comment: This is a very good solution especially working with tabs. Switching to a far away tab (further than setOffscreenPageLimit()) will trigger the onDestroyView method on the Fragment (otherwise the "Duplicate Id problem will persist), BUT launching another activity will not, so when you hit back from the launched activity you'll see that the fragment is still there.

Comment: Thank you soo much for this. Worked like a charm. Stuck with this issue for 5 to 6 hours. It's just to remove the added views from the fragment.

Answer (score 4):

This fixed my problem:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(rootView==null){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MapFragment, container, false);
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

More here:
https://colinyeoh.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/android-mapfragment-exception-when-clicked-twice/

Comment: PERFECT! Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                         .findFragmentById(R.id.mymap);
    if (f != null) 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
```

Actually you don't need to use this inside an onDestroyView. My case was to remove an inflated layout with a SupportMapFragment, and that was it.