# Error inflate SupportMapFragment onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, supportmapfragment, onconfigurationchanged

I need to load the correct layout, depending on the orientation.
But the problem is that I do not want to reload code, but simply reload the layout.

I tried `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` but when that line is executed, I get the following error:

- "Error inflating class fragment"
- "Duplicate id 0x7f0f00b9, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0f00a9 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

These errors corresponds to SupportMapFragment.

How I solved it?

This activity has `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` For that reason I want to reload the layout in `onConfigurationChanged()`

***EDIT***

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/header">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.57"
        android:id="@+id/status_layout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="271dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="NO DISPONIBLE"
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.16"
        android:id="@+id/info_layout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="000-A"
            android:id="@+id/licencia"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="000-WTF"
            android:id="@+id/matricula"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.40"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:visibility="visible">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/action_pick_passenger"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/pick_button"
        android:onClick="onClickPickButton"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/destinationButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/action_on_target"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/start_button"
        android:onClick="onClickDestinationButton"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/action_available"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/pick_button_pressed"
        android:onClick="onClickStartButton"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/action_cancel_service"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/start_button_pressed"
        android:onClick="onClickCancelButton"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/action_not_available"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:onClick="onClickStopButton"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/action_back_to_service"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/start_button_pressed"
        android:onClick="onClickBackButton"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cashButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/cash"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:onClick="cashPayment"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/paythunderButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/pt_payment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:onClick="ptPayment"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/pt_rosa"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tpvButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/tpv_payment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:onClick="tpvPayment"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:onClick="onClickCancelButton" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/snackbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/paypad"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/info"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button android:text="1"
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button android:text="2"
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button android:text="3"
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="0"
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button android:text="4"
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button android:text="5"
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button android:text="6"
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button android:text=","
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button android:text="7"
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button android:text="8"
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button android:text="9"
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button android:text="DEL"
            android:onClick="btnPressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_cantidad"
        android:layout_above="@+id/number"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_200"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|right">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/amount"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:digits="0123456789,."
                    android:ems="15"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:hint="@string/amount_000"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:maxLength="8"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="50dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:text="@string/simbolo_euro"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="50sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your code where you are getting error..

Comment: paste your activity_main.xml

Comment: the activity_main.xml is similar on landscape and portrait @RishabhMahatha

Comment: make a landscape layout and call in `onConfigurationChanged()`

Comment: @W4R10CK I don't understand you.

I have 2 layout, one for portrait an other to landscape. The idea is load the layout depending of orientation. But when I `setContentView()` the app crash with the mistakes I said earlier

Comment: @SergioAntonioSnchezCamarero i'm little confused with your question, please explain little.

Comment: @W4R10CK I have to load/reload layout when the orientation change but without reload code of Activity, only layout. The problem is when I `setContentView()` SupportMapFragment crash

Comment: did you have same layout for both the orientation ?

Comment: @W4R10CK no, the layout are similar, but the buttons have different orientations/colocations

Comment: can you post code how you doing this, which causes error ?

Comment: Try This http://stackoverflow.com/a/27592123/2599596

Comment: Use map view instead of map fragment

Comment: @W4R10CK `    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }`

Comment: @NaveenKumarM 3this is when you have an FragmentActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

In place of:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.40"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout" />
```

And in activity.java,Initialise mapview like this:

```
   private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

     @Override
        public void onResume() {
            mapView.onResume();
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mapView.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mapView.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            mapView.onLowMemory();
        }
```

Comment: don't load de Map, load de icon, zoom, etc. but not load the map

Comment: Then you have network problem in your testing device.

Comment: it'r possible beacause y my job there are some network, but how that appears when change MapFragment to Mapview.

Comment: the network doesn't the problem, I tried it with 4 network and with my data mobile

Comment: Actually the problem is when you are using map fragment its a static fragment and you can not replace or add static fragment you can only perform hide and show.so when you are rotating your device the fragment get refreshed but there is already map fragment which can not be replaced that is why you are getting same id issue that's it.

Comment: yes this is my problem, are there any solutions?¿ because el MapView don't load de map :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134376/discussion-between-rishabh-mahatha-and-sergio-antonio-snchez-camarero).