# IllegalArgumentException caused by binary XML file (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

i have a basic navigation with 3 tabs. One of them contains a fragment with google maps in it. However the navigation isn't good, it keeps crashing after i select the tab for the second time.

It says it is because of the XML file of the maps which in my opinion doesn't have anything wrong. Can anyone see my error which i am blinded for right now?

Logcat :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at com.example.dell.animalz.MapsFragment.onCreateView(MapsFragment.java:22)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1297)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
        at      

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
        at   
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
        at     
android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:555)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495)
        at com.example.dell.animalz.HomeActivity.onTabSelected(HomeActivity.java:67)
        at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:674)
        at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1217)
        at     
com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:976)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f070067, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
```

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

ViewPager mViewPager = null;
private TabsMenuAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

private String []tabs = {"News", "Animalz", "Maps"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager1);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsMenuAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for(String tab_names : tabs){
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_names).setTabListener(this));
    }
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
}
```

Maps.java

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_layout, container, false);
    return rootView;

  }
}
```

Maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance !

Comment: Note the cause of the exception: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f070067, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Comment: why don't you add that fragment dynamically instead of by xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the MapFragment in the `onDestroyView()` method of the Fragment that contains the map, with referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484640/1638739), you must do the following:

```
// override the onDestroyView of the fragment
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                         .findFragmentById(R.id.the_map);
    if (f != null) 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
}
```

Comment: That worked bro, the application stopped crashing. However the errors in the logcat keep happenning at launch of the app.

Comment: If you need to remove it by code then why do you add fragment by xml? Will not it be good to add by code itself to handle everything at one place?

Comment: @MehulJoisar it will be good, but I think adding it by xml won't hurt, as he will just create an instance from the xml and then remove that instance

Comment: Yes thanks for your implication muhammed, unfortunately can't upvote your answer...

Comment: @zakbennani never mind, it's ok, but the reason is ?

Comment: 15 reputation points to do so, btw i have to apply this to all fragments right?

Comment: yes you have to, even if no error shows up with other fragments, it's good for clearness and safety

Answer (score 0):

Every time check your parent view empty or not. If yes then remove. Change your **Maps.java**.

```
private static View view;    
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup group,Bundle bundle)
{
    if(view!=null)
    {
        ViewGroup parent =(ViewGroup)view.getParent();
        if(parent!=null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try{
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps, group, false);
        ........

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("ERROR", ""+e);
    }

    return view;
}
```