# App crashes when opening Map Fragment twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps

I'm designing my app with backwards comptibility so I have implemented the support and design libraries to use things like navigation drawer and other effects asociated with new android versions.

The navigation drawer manages a total of 5 fragments. One of these fragments contains a map:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

-

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);

        /*Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment*/
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

And this is how I manage the fragments from navigation drawer on mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            displayFragment(menuItem.getItemId());
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return true;
        }
    });


private void displayFragment(int itemId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.navigation_item_1:
            fragment = new StatusFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_status);
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_item_2:
            fragment = new LocationFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_location);
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_item_3:
            fragment = new SetupFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_setup);
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_item_4:
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_profile);
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_item_5:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_about);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        /*set the toolbar title*/
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

The thing is that if I open this map fragment, it works fine, but if I then go to another fragment, and then come back to the map fragment, the app crashes showing this in the logcat:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at com.masmr.detgprs.LocationFragment.onCreateView(LocationFragment.java:102)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #11: Duplicate id 0x7f0c0090, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4791)
        at 

android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:41)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:826)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:172)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.masmr.detgprs.LocationFragment.onCreateView(LocationFragment.java:102)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The 102 line refers to map fragment's onCreateView()'s first line where I inflate the map_layout.

Comment: remove MapFragment in onDestroy()

Comment: @MD How should I do that? Provide an answer and if works I'll accept it

Comment: This is a duplicate question. [Asked here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just implement in your  `Fragment`

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroyView ()
    {
        try{
          MapFragment fragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
          FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          ft.remove(fragment);
          ft.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
      super.onDestroyView();  
  }
```

Comment: Just one note, on `ft.remove(fragment)` it shows it in red and says that: `remove(android.app.fragment) in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to (com.google.android.gsm.maps.SupportMapFragment)`

Comment: used `SupportMapFragment` then

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

**fragment_map.xml**:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
     android:id="@+id/mapView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**MyMapFragment.java**:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private MapView mapView;
```

on **onCreaeView()** of **Fragment**:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initializaMap(rootView, savedInstanceState);
}

private void initializaMap(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        switch (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity())) {
        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
            mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (mapView != null) {
                mMap = mapView.getMap();
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                UiSettings mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(7.0f));
                mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);    
                mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            }
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
            break;
        default:
        }
    }
```

on **onResume()**:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
    if(mapView!=null){
        mapView.onResume();
    }   
}
```

on **onDestroy()**:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
    if(mapView!=null){
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

on **onLowMemory()**:

```
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
super.onLowMemory();
    if(mapView!=null){
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

**Done**