# my fragment display white screen instead of google maps, why?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have to set up maps fragment for PagerView in the main activity. This is the code of fragment.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.doctorfinderapp.doctorfinder.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class DoctorMapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doctor_maps_fragment, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.map,mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
    googleMap = gMap;
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

this is doctor_maps_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map" />
```

how can i fix it? when i stay on map the layout display a white screen and i don't know what is the issue.

Comment: It looks like it would be better for you to just make your Fragment extend SupportMapFragment, take a look at the TabLayout solution in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32579020/4409409

Comment: Thanks but it was not my same problem.

Comment: I don't think the root element can be a fragment tag. Why not give it a framelayout and use SupportMapFragment.newInstance() and then use it to replace the framelayout.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#newInstance%28%29

Comment: There is now another exception

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things, your layout is wrong, since you're using 'MapView' there is no 'android:name' attribute.

If you wanna use MapView and not SupprtMapFragment change your layout to:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Also you must call the mapViews onCreate function, otherwise nothing will be shown, so change your onCreateView to:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doctor_maps_fragment, container, false);
    mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(null);
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. it cause this exception: fragment.DoctorMapsFragment.onCreateView(DoctorMapsFragment.java:7). I think i change from mapView to SupportMapFragment

Comment: That's just the row, not the exception :)

Comment: I answered myself for complete exception above.

Comment: I edited with complete exception, anyone can help me?:D

Comment: Ahh i see, it's a bug :( Take a look here : https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021

Comment: The is not solution:( people say that the bug caused from mobile phone sdcard less. I can't force users to buy an sdcard for use my application. There is an other way to implement google map in a fragment?

Comment: If it really is what is stated in the link @Andre_Classen suggests. I'm pretty sure that sooner or later Google will fix it. I think for now you will have to go for the solution stated there for it is only a temporary problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doctor_maps_fragment, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, mMapFragment).commit();
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return view;

}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/map"/>
```

Comment: What exception do you have?

Comment: Edited. Forget to commit the changes to the fragmenttransaction with .commit(). Try it again.