# Unable to Re-inflate a fragment dialog Xamarin and C#

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I  am having an issue with my fragment dialog. I have a listview & when I click on a single list view item, I am able to move in to the fragment dialog.

But when I go back to the parent that is holding the listview & try to re-enter into the fragment dialog I am getting this error.

`Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment`

The line that is giving me the error is

`var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_preview_busn, container, false);`

Here is the XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/dialogLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:minWidth="300dp"
android:minHeight="200dp"
android:weightSum="100"
android:gravity="center">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="15"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:background="@drawable/progressBarDesign"
    android:id="@+id/fragProgress"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtName" />
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/dialogLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/dialogLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <TextView
            android:text="Address:  "
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/labAddess" />
        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtName" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/dialogLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/dialogLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <TextView
            android:text="Number:  "
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/labNumber" />
        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtAddress" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/dialogLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/dialogLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <TextView
            android:text="Email:  "
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/labEmail" />
        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtNumber" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/dialogLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/dialogLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <TextView
            android:text="Website:  "
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/labEmail" />
        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/txtWebsite"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtEmail" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:text="Hours"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:id="@+id/labHours"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtWebsite" />
<TextView
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtHours"
    android:layout_below="@id/labEmail" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30sp"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:paddingTop="6sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#4A115C"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_down_arrow"
    android:id="@+id/downArrow"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/dialogLayout"
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Code block that is calling the dialog fragment. This code is located inside of a listview_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e).

```
Android.App.FragmentTransaction transaction_prev = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().AddToBackStack(null);
        dialog_preview_busn previewBusn = new dialog_preview_busn(gName, gAddress, gZip, gNumber, gEmail, gWebsite, gHours, gImage);
        previewBusn.Show(transaction_prev, "Dialog Preview Business");
```

The Full output from the debugger from when the error happens:

```
        Unhandled Exception:

    Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

    09-27 13:43:22.963 D/Mono    ( 2359): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
    09-27 13:43:22.963 D/Mono    ( 2359): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
    09-27 13:43:22.963 D/Mono    ( 2359): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
    09-27 13:43:22.963 D/Mono    ( 2359): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
    09-27 13:43:22.963 D/Mono    ( 2359): Probing '__android_log_print'.
    09-27 13:43:22.963 D/Mono    ( 2359): Found as '__android_log_print'.
    09-27 13:43:22.983 I/MonoDroid( 2359): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
    09-27 13:43:23.003 I/MonoDroid( 2359): Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment ---> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #1: Duplicate id 0x7f0a001d, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a001c with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
    09-27 13:43:23.003 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException stack trace ---
    09-27 13:43:23.003 I/MonoDroid( 2359): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #1: Duplicate id 0x7f0a001d, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a001c with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
    09-27 13:43:23.003 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4940)
    09-27 13:43:23.003 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
    09-27 13:43:23.003 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    09-27 13:43:23.003 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    09-27 13:43:23.003 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    09-27 13:43:23.003 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at md5acfef63ba52ffd159bb4b4b5411a5ab5.dialog_preview_busn.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.003 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at md5acfef63ba52ffd159bb4b4b5411a5ab5.dialog_preview_busn.onCreateView(dialog_preview_busn.java:45)
    09-27 13:43:23.003 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    09-27 13:43:23.013 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException stack trace ---
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #1: Duplicate id 0x7f0a001d, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a001c with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4940)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at md5acfef63ba52ffd159bb4b4b5411a5ab5.dialog_preview_busn.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at md5acfef63ba52ffd159bb4b4b5411a5ab5.dialog_preview_busn.onCreateView(dialog_preview_busn.java:45)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
    09-27 13:43:23.023 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00085] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11283 
    09-27 13:43:23.033 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:350 
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (System.Xml.XmlReader parser, Android.Views.ViewGroup root, Boolean attachToRoot) [0x0005b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Views.LayoutInflater.cs:725 
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   at My_Town_App.Droid.dialog_preview_busn.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x0000b] in C:\Users\Owner\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\My_Town_App\My_Town_App\My_Town_App.Droid\dialog_preview_busn.cs:99 
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   at Android.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_inflater, IntPtr native_container, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00022] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Fragment.cs:1612 
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:7764fb92-ef49-4334-84ad-92014396e88a (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   --- End of managed Android.Views.InflateException stack trace ---
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at md5acfef63ba52ffd159bb4b4b5411a5ab5.dialog_preview_busn.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at md5acfef63ba52ffd159bb4b4b5411a5ab5.dialog_preview_busn.onCreateView(dialog_preview_busn.java:45)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    09-27 13:43:23.043 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #1: Duplicate id 0x7f0a001d, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a001c with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4940)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  ... 20 more
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):   --- End of managed Android.Views.InflateException stack trace ---
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at md5acfef63ba52ffd159bb4b4b5411a5ab5.dialog_preview_busn.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at md5acfef63ba52ffd159bb4b4b5411a5ab5.dialog_preview_busn.onCreateView(dialog_preview_busn.java:45)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-27 13:43:23.053 I/MonoDroid( 2359): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #1: Duplicate id 0x7f0a001d, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a001c with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
    09-27 13:43:23.063 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4940)
    09-27 13:43:23.063 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
    09-27 13:43:23.063 I/MonoDroid( 2359):  ... 20 more
    09-27 13:43:23.073 D/Mono    ( 2359): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
    09-27 13:43:23.073 D/Mono    ( 2359): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
    09-27 13:43:23.073 D/Mono    ( 2359): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
    09-27 13:43:23.073 D/Mono    ( 2359): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
    An unhandled exception occured.

    In mgmain JNI_OnLoad
```

Comment: Show us more code. Where is this line of code located in? What code block? Can you also attach the full exception? It will have the respective line of the exception.

Comment: `Duplicate id 0x7f0a001d, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a001c with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi

So you may want to use `replace()` and not inflate fragments inside fragments!

Comment: Okay so inside of the dialog_prev_busn where I am calling the map I need to replace the map fragment?

Comment: You are inflating `Resource.Layout.dialog_preview_busn` twice. However it already has a fragment here. You should instead just replace the fragment using a `<FrameLayout>` or similar. I personally use `<FrameLayout>` as a "container" to house any fragments in my layouts. Then use `.replace` to swap fragments.

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/fragment/create_a_fragment/

Comment: Jon thank you for all of the help with is problem. is there anyway that I could use a dialogfragment instead of just a fragment?

Comment: Open up another question about that. I believe this one is solved. I'll provide an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace gives the following error:

`Duplicate id 0x7f0a001d, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a001c with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`

You can read more about this issue here: [Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi)

So you may want to use `replace()` to ensure you do not inflate fragments inside fragments. Ensure that you remove your previous fragment before adding another.

There's a note about this here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a `<fragment>`. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.