# Error Inflating class autocompleteFragment with viewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, runtime-error, placeautocompletefragment

The crash is when i switch the page from 2 to 0 or 1. 
And when i Comment the auto Complete Fragment at activity_maps.xml

Please help me.

> --------- beginning of crash 
>   12-04 01:31:01.005 12693-12693/com.handsomelee.gotroute E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.handsomelee.gotroute, PID: 12693
>                                                                             android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #10: Duplicate id 0x7f0f00e4, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment
>                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2315)
>                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5901)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:41)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
>                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
>                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                                                                                 at com.handsomelee.gotroute.Services.GoogleMapSystem.onCreateView(GoogleMapSystem.java:41)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:792)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2209)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:663)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:625)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:617)
>                                                                                 at com.handsomelee.gotroute.MainActivity$1.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:73)
>                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1165)
>                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1158)
>                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1128)
>                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1427)
>                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1537)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                        
> --------- beginning of system

this is my MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
  switch (position) {
    case 0:
      if(tab1 == null){
        tab1 = new MapsActivity(R.id.mapView, R.layout.activity_maps, GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
      }
      return tab1;

    case 1:
      if(tab2 == null)
      tab2 = new CarParkingActivity();
      return tab2;

    case 2:
      if(tab3 == null)
      tab3 = new ReportActivity();
      return tab3;

    default:
      return null;
  }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
  return 3;
}
```

MapsActivity.java

```
@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
  rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutActivityId, viewGroup, false);
  mapView = ((MapView) rootView.findViewById(mapViewId));
  mapView.onCreate(bundle);
  mapView.getMapAsync(this);
  addOn();
  return rootView;
}
@Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  mMap = googleMap;
  mMap.setMapType(googleMapType);
  mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
  mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);
  mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
}
}
```

activity_maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context="com.handsomelee.gotroute.Controller.ReportActivity">

        <fragment
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:id="@+id/placeSearch"
                android:layout_weight="0.67"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                android:layout_weight="0.78"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:apiKey="@string/test_google_api"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/placeSearch"/>
      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

ReportActivity.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_report, container, false);

  spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  String[] array_Spiner = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.reports_array);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_Spiner);

  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    ~
  });

  return rootView;
}
```

activity_report.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.handsomelee.gotroute.Controller.ReportActivity">

      <Spinner
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:id="@+id/spinner"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
              android:overlapAnchor="false"
              android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
              app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Avoid questions with too many lines of code. Questions asking us to debug your code are considered off-topic. Consider reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Refer to [this question's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19815266/7970936) It appears to be an issue with your mapview.

Comment: @DannyMichelin But When i remove the mapview. it also got the problem.

Comment: @Mateus thans for your advise. I had updated my post already

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. 
The problem seems like is the fragment id duplicated when the view is created.
so I add the Code below at my MapActivity to remove it.

```
@Override
  public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    android.app.Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.placeSearch);
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
  }
```