# Type mismatch. Required: Fragment, Found: PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, placeautocompletefragment, child-fragment

I bumped into a

> Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for
>   placeAutocompleteFragment

error, and so i followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19815266/5076153) to try and fix it by adding the placeAutocompleteFragment via a fragment transaction using the `childFragmentManager`

**fragment class `onCreateView`**

```
val fm: FragmentManager = childFragmentManager
var placeAutocompleteFragment: PlaceAutocompleteFragment? = fm.findFragmentByTag("placeAutocompleteFragment") as PlaceAutocompleteFragment?

if (placeAutocompleteFragment == null){
    placeAutocompleteFragment = PlaceAutocompleteFragment()
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.address_layout, placeAutocompleteFragment, "placeAutocompleteFragment").commit()
}
```

**.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
...
...
...
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/address_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_search_bar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
...
...
...
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem now is on the line

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.address_layout, placeAutocompleteFragment, "placeAutocompleteFragment").commit()
```

I get a type mistake for `placeAutocompleteFragment` Type mismatch. Required: Fragment, Found: PlaceAutocompleteFragment?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

getChildFragmentManager will return support library version of FragmentManager. So you should pass fragment object which inherits support library version of Fragment.

But PlaceAutocompleteFragment inherits android.app.Fragment.

**Solution**

Using [SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) instead PlaceAutocompleteFragment.

Comment: thank you so much, you're a life saver. I've spent hours trying to work around this lol