# AutocompleteSearchFragment in Dialog gives InflateException

Tags: android, android-fragments, autocomplete, dialog, google-places-api

I am using the Google Map's Places API's `AutoCompleteSearchFragment` in a `Dialog`. The error that I am getting occurs when I launch the dialog, close it, then relaunch it.

**Error Message:**

> Error inflating class fragment. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #69: Duplicate id 0x7f0a0027, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a00c7 with another fragment for `com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSearchFragmet

**My code:**

```
Dialog alert = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
alert.setContentView(R.layout.forgot_info);
alert.setCancelable(true);
alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteSupportFragment =
   (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.auto2);
```

The error also goes on to mention `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView` and `android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag`.

Is it possible that the **duplicate id** error is occurring because the `Activity` believes that there is more than one `AutocompleteSearchFragments`?

If so, how would I be able to delete or remove the `AutocompleteSearchFragment` once the `Dialog` is closed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi

Comment: Thank you for the link @Bek, but I'd already tried those answers and they hadn't worked for me. I think it's because the `AutocompleteSearchFragment` is a little different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem, *for those that it may help later on*.

In order to prevent the `Activity` from thinking that there is more than one `AutocompleteSearchFragment` with the same ID each time I open the `Dialog`, I set a `onDismissListener` for the `Dialog` in order to remove the `AutocompleteSearchFragment`:

**The code:**

```
alert.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
               remove((Fragment) autocompleteSupportFragment).commit();
    }
});
```

What the code above does is when the `Dialog` called `alert` is dismissed, it uses the `SupportFragmentManager` to remove that `AutocompleteSearchFragment`.