# Fragment with Map crashes app when back button is pressed or when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an `Activity` that loads 2 tabs in the `ActionBar`. Tab 1 loads a `Fragment` that will will inflate a `WebView`, while Tab 2 loads a `Fragment` with a map. Initially, I have the problem of changing tabs that causes the app to crash. I have followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074625/mapfragment-in-action-bar-tabs/14466954#14466954) and implemented `onDestroyView()`.

The problem now is that if I press the back button from Tab 1 (`WebView`), it exits the `Activity` properly. But if I do it on Tab 2 (map), the app crashes. The exact same scenario applies to when I change the orientation. I am convinced that it has something to do with the `onDestroyView()`, but I am not sure what it is.

I have even attempted to `Override` the back button, but nothing works.

Here is my code to provide some context:

The Activity Class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Displaying the tabs by calling ActionBar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    //Details Tab
    String label1 = getResources().getString(R.string.details);
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label1);
    TabListener<DetailsFragment> t1 = new TabListener<DetailsFragment>(this, label1, DetailsFragment.class);
    tab.setTabListener(t1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    //Map Tab
    String label2 = getResources().getString(R.string.map);
    tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label2);
    TabListener<MapFragment> t2 = new TabListener<MapFragment>(this, label2, MapFragment.class);
    tab.setTabListener(t2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}

private class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /**
     * Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
     * 
     * @param activity
     *            The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
     * @param tag
     *            The identifier tag for the fragment
     * @param clz
     *            The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
     */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);

        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
} }
```

DetailsFragment:

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.morning, container, false);
    WebView webview = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.details);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pools/details.html");
    return v;
} }
```

MapFragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

static final LatLng mapLatLng = new LatLng("some numbers", "some numbers");
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
    map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    Marker amksc = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mapLatLng).title("Map"));

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mapLatLng, 18)); 
    return v;
}


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    MapFragment destroyMe = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (destroyMe != null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(destroyMe).commit();
    }
} }
```

Thanks for reading such a long post. Any help is greatly appreciated. I will be away for awhile without my laptop (15 days to be exact), so I may not be able to respond and test out your answer, but rest assured that I will =)

Thanks in advance!

EDITED to include Error Log (Not sure how to format it)

```
04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779): java.lang.NullPointerException

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1380)

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:430)

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)

04-25 11:27:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(21779):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you also post error log?

Comment: I have added the LogCat errors in the question. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem like complete error stack. You can format it like you did your code.

Comment: I got this from the LogCat tab of Eclipse. The Error Log tab didn't have anything. And I removed some parts with regards to the Google Mpas not loading. This is due to the use of different keystores. I usually just export the app using the actual keystore to test the app on my phone

Comment: hav u enabled google maps permission in manifest file

Comment: Google Maps isn't a problem. I can display the map properly. The problem is with the app crashing after pressing back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved both the back button and orientation change problem.

The trick here is to not use `onDestroyView()`, but to change the way the fragments are handled. instead of `ft.attach(mFragment)` and `ft.detach(mFragment)`, I changed them to `ft.show(mFragment)` and `ft.hide(mFragment)`.

As for the orientation change causing the app to crash, I believe (do correct me if I am wrong) that as long as you do not have an alternative landscape layout, you can add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to the manifest for this activity, like this:

```
<activity 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name="MyFragmentActivity" 
        android:label="@string/fragmentActivity" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The GoogleMap needs a little bit of time to load, so it could return null if you want use it.
Try moving this code in the onActivityCreated() method of your MapFragment

```
map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
Marker amksc = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mapLatLng).title("Map"));

map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mapLatLng, 18));
```

That used to work for me.
Be sure to check out the [Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

it was work for me.. try it 
the below code write in the onDestory() method

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() { 
if (fragment != null
                        && getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                                fragment.getId()) != null) {

                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment)
                            .commit();
                    fragment = null;
                }
}
```